# Selecting list entries with a True False index list of similar length

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to determine which elements in a list are divisible by a specific number, lets say 3.

I generate a list with numbers:

```
numbers = Range[10];
```

I then use `Divisible` to create another list of equal length that has True and False entries related to whether or not the entry in `numbers` are divisible by 3:

```
In[1] := test = Divisible[numbers, 3]
Out[1] := {False, False, True, False, False, True, False, False, True, False}
```

The resulting list `test` thus acts as an index.

How would I go about adding all the items in `numbers` to a new list if their corresponding item in `test` is `True`?

Comment: Mike, regarding your edit: closing a question is not a judgement on the value of the question contents; it has more to do with site management and improved searching. For instance, personally I upvoted your question (it is well written and clear), and also voted to mark it as duplicate. Your specific question was answered below (`Pick` is tailor-made for your task); the closure just establishes a permanent link between this question and other(s), perhaps more general, that people interested in the topic of your question are likely to find useful.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation MarcoB, that makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Pick](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pick.html) does exactly what you need:

```
numbers = Range[10];
test = Divisible[numbers, 3];
Pick[numbers, test]
```

> {3, 6, 9}

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to use a conditional inside `Divisible` to simultaneously check for divisibility? Say, if I want to check if a number is either divisible by 3 OR 5?

Comment: @Mike, i am not sure if you can do it with `Divisible` but you can use `Divisors` and `MemberQ` like `MemberQ[Divisors[#], 3 | 5] & /@ Range[10]`

Answer (score 3):

you can use Select without having to create the list of Boolean values `True`, `False`explicitly

```
Select[Range[10], Divisible[#, 3] &]
(* {3,6,9} *)
```

Alternatively one can use `Extract`

```
Extract[#, Position[Mod[#, 3], 0]] &@Range[10]
```

`Cases` can also be used

```
Cases[Range[10], _?(Mod[#, 3] == 0 &)]
```

using `Patterns`

```
Range[10] /. x_ /; ! Mod[x, 3] == 0 :> Sequence[]
```

using `Part`

```
Range[10][[3 ;; ;; 3]]
```

there are many ways you can use to get the answer in Mathematica.